# How do I extract Ref<a,b,c> from Option<Ref<a,b,c>> in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a generic hashtable that would allow me to use a either std HashMap or DashMap under the hood

```
use dashmap::DashMap;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub enum GenericHashTable<K, V> {
    HashMap(HashMap<K, V>),
    DashMap(DashMap<K, V>),
}

impl<K, V> GenericHashTable<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn new_hashmap() -> Self {
        GenericHashTable::HashMap(HashMap::new())
    }

    fn new_dashmap() -> Self {
        GenericHashTable::DashMap(DashMap::new())
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        match self {
            GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.insert(key, value),
            GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.insert(key, value),
        }
    }
    
    fn remove(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<V> {
        match self {
            GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.remove(key),
            GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.remove(key).map(|(_, v)| v),
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V> {
        match self {
            GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get(key),
            GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get(key),
        }
    }
   
    fn get_mut(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<&mut V> {
        match self {
             GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key),
             GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key).map(|mut v| v),
        }
    }
}
```

I have issues with `get` and `get_mut` methods

With `get`, its

```
`match` arms have incompatible types
expected enum `std::option::Option<&V>`
   found enum `std::option::Option<dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, K, V>>`
```

`get_mut` is similar

```
`match` arms have incompatible types
expected enum `std::option::Option<&mut V>`
   found enum `std::option::Option<dashmap::mapref::one::RefMut<'_, K, V>>`
```

So I need to get `std::option::Option<dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, K, V>>` to `std::option::Option<&V>`

I tried `map.get(key).value()`, thinking this would extract the `V` from `Ref<'_, K, V>>` but I got the following error

```
no method named `value` found for enum `std::option::Option` in the current scope
method not found in `std::option::Option<dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, K, V>>`
the method `value` exists on the type `dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, K, V>`
```

So I think what I need to do is extract `Ref<'_, K, V>` out of `Option` before I can try to access its value.

This seems very simple and yet I can't figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dashmap `Ref` and `RefMut` types are so-called "guards."  They implement the `Deref*` traits as appropriate, which allows them to be used a lot like a reference in most cases.  The reason guards exist is usually so that they can implement [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html), which allows them to do something when you're finished with the reference.  This is exactly what the Rust built-in `RefCell` type does, for example -- its guards exist to manage and enforce the correctness of the internal refcount while also ensuring that you can only reach the contained value while your usage is reflected by the refcount.

The problem you'll run into is that any reference you obtain from a guard can't outlive the guard itself, which means you can't return the reference and then discard the guard.  If you could do this, you could return a reference from a `RefCell` after discarding the guard, for example, which would allow mutable aliasing in violation of Rust's safety rules!  Ultimately, **you have to return the guard** if you want to allow access to the reference the guard contains.

The simple answer is that you can't do this the way you're trying to.

The longer answer is that you *can* do this but it's a bit tricky because the reference types of both maps aren't the same, as you've discovered.  (This is what the compiler is telling you when it says "match arms have incompatible types.")

One approach would be creating your own guard types, which can just be an enum containing either a bare reference or a dashmap guard, then you return those from your getter methods.  Implement the appropriate `Deref*` types so that your guards automatically deref to the referent, just like other guards do.

Here is a working example:

```
use dashmap::DashMap;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

pub enum GenericHashTable<K, V> {
    HashMap(HashMap<K, V>),
    DashMap(DashMap<K, V>),
}

pub enum Ref<'a, K, V> {
    Bare(&'a V),
    DashMap(dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'a, K, V>),
}

impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> Deref for Ref<'a, K, V> {
    type Target = V;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Bare(r) => r,
            Self::DashMap(r) => Deref::deref(r),
        }
    }
}

pub enum RefMut<'a, K, V> {
    Bare(&'a mut V),
    DashMap(dashmap::mapref::one::RefMut<'a, K, V>),
}

impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> Deref for RefMut<'a, K, V> {
    type Target = V;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Bare(r) => r,
            Self::DashMap(r) => Deref::deref(r),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> DerefMut for RefMut<'a, K, V> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Bare(r) => r,
            Self::DashMap(r) => DerefMut::deref_mut(r),
        }
    }
}

impl<K, V> GenericHashTable<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    // Other methods removed for brevity.

    fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &K) -> Option<Ref<'a, K, V>> {
        match self {
            GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get(key).map(Ref::Bare),
            GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get(key).map(Ref::DashMap),
        }
    }
   
    fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, key: &K) -> Option<RefMut<'a, K, V>> {
        match self {
             GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key).map(RefMut::Bare),
             GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key).map(RefMut::DashMap),
        }
    }
}
```

Rust's drop glue will automatically run the drop code for any contained dashmap guard when your guard is dropped, so this perfectly and safely wraps dashmap's own guards.

---

Here is an alternative approach using boxing.  The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to create your own guard types.  This makes maintenance of your code simpler, as well as making it easier to add new types of maps later with their own guards as you don't have to modify your guards to handle the new guards.

The disadvantage is there is a heap allocation to create a guard, and an extra level of indirection when dereferencing a guard.

```
    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<Box<dyn Deref<Target=V> + '_>> {
        match self {
            GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get(key)
                .map(|v| -> Box<dyn Deref<Target=V>> { Box::new(v) }),
            GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get(key)
                .map(|v| -> Box<dyn Deref<Target=V>> { Box::new(v) }),
        }
    }

    fn get_mut(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<Box<dyn DerefMut<Target=V> + '_>> {
        match self {
             GenericHashTable::HashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key)
                .map(|v| -> Box<dyn DerefMut<Target=V>> { Box::new(v) }),
             GenericHashTable::DashMap(map) => map.get_mut(key)
                .map(|v| -> Box<dyn DerefMut<Target=V>> { Box::new(v) }),
        }
    }
```

---

Perhaps a better approach than the above two, simply write your own trait with common map functionality and implement it on both other map types!

```
use dashmap::{mapref::one::{Ref, RefMut}, DashMap};
use std::{hash::Hash, ops::{Deref, DerefMut}, collections::HashMap};

trait HashTable {
    type Key;
    type Value;

    type Ref<'a>: Deref<Target = Self::Value> + 'a where Self: 'a;
    type RefMut<'a>: DerefMut<Target = Self::Value> + 'a where Self: 'a;

    fn insert(&mut self, key: Self::Key, value: Self::Value) -> Option<Self::Value>;
    fn remove(&mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Value>;

    fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Ref<'a>>;
    fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::RefMut<'a>>;
}

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V> HashTable for HashMap<K, V> {
    type Key = K;
    type Value = V;

    type Ref<'a> = &'a V where Self: 'a;
    type RefMut<'a> = &'a mut V where Self: 'a;

    fn insert(&mut self, key: Self::Key, value: Self::Value) -> Option<Self::Value> {
        HashMap::insert(self, key, value)
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Value> {
        HashMap::remove(self, key)
    }

    fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Ref<'a>> {
        HashMap::get(self, key)
    }

    fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::RefMut<'a>> {
        HashMap::get_mut(self, key)
    }
}

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V> HashTable for DashMap<K, V> {
    type Key = K;
    type Value = V;

    type Ref<'a> = Ref<'a, K, V> where Self: 'a;
    type RefMut<'a> = RefMut<'a, K, V> where Self: 'a;

    fn insert(&mut self, key: Self::Key, value: Self::Value) -> Option<Self::Value> {
        DashMap::insert(self, key, value)
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Value> {
        DashMap::remove(self, key).map(|(_, v)| v)
    }

    fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Ref<'a>> {
        DashMap::get(self, key)
    }

    fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, key: &Self::Key) -> Option<Self::RefMut<'a>> {
        DashMap::get_mut(self, key)
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked! Thanks for the detailed explanation. My goal is to implement 1 struct for all and make development easier but now it seems more complicated than i had intended.

Comment: @user2066671 Indeed, it can be complicated. What we're doing here is making returned references polymorphic, but unlike a lot of other languages, we have to implement the polymorphism ourselves. There is a way that you can let the language implement the polymorphism for you, but this requires boxing. Basically you'd return a `Option<Box<dyn Deref<Target=V> + '_>>` and box the reference or the dashmap guard. If you'd like an example of that approach I can add one to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i would love to see an example. Would there be any drawbacks by using boxing? My goal is to expose the high performant datastructures without compromise

Comment: @user2066671 Both approaches have trade-offs. The approach I give in my answer is probably more performant than boxing because boxing adds a level of indirection and a heap allocation. On the other hand, boxing requires less code to implement. (Both require the same amount of code to _use_ so if performance is your concern then the enum approach is better.)

Comment: @user2066671 I added an example. You basically use a dynamic `Deref*` as the guard type. This works because both `&V` and dashmap's `Ref` implement `Deref`, and ditto for `&mut V` and dashmap's `RefMut` implementing `DerefMut`.

Comment: @user2066671 Another approach would be to instead create a map-like trait and implement it on both types of maps. Rust allows you to implement your own traits on foreign types, which is something none of the most popular languages really let you do.

Comment: @user2066671 I've added an example of the trait approach.

Comment: Thank you for the posting the trait examples, that seems the cleanest. I do have some questions.

Comment: @user2066671 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252648/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-user2066671).